# How to keep indent in lists with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.page-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}
.page-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}
.page-content li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: green;
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: 34px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">

  <ul>
    <li>short bullet</li>
    <li>short bullet</li>
    <li>long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heabsx6o/)

As you can see, if a list-item ever goes on to a second line it loses the `li` `padding`/`margin`.

Is there any way to allow the subsequent lines to match up to the first line?

Comment: This is one of those one's where the first thing I think is "you didn't even try a quick web search first did ya?" then see a bunch of repeated answers from guys seeking easy points instead of closing it as a duplicate, even though there's so many variations I'm not even sure which to use to mark it as duplicate either... TGIF

Comment: I did search first @ChrisW. and tried some solutions but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `margin-left:-20px` to `li:before`

```css
.page-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}

.page-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}

.page-content li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: green;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left:-20px;
  line-height: 34px;
  list-style-position:inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">

  <ul>
    <li>short bullet</li>
    <li>short bullet</li>
    <li>long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Another solution could be using `text-indent:-1em` in `li`

```css
.page-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}
.page-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}
.page-content li {
  text-indent: -1em
}
.page-content li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: green;
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: 34px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">

  <ul>
    <li>short bullet</li>
    <li>short bullet</li>
    <li>long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.  Add some left padding to the `li` element and then use absolute positioning to shift the marker to the left.

The approach gives you a lot of control over the position of the marker.
In addition, the marker position will remain stable if you change the size or style of the marker element.

```css
.page-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}

.page-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
}
.page-content li {
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.page-content li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: @green;
  margin-right: 0px;
  line-height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">

  <ul>
    <li>short bullet</li>
    <li>short bullet</li>
    <li>long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet long bullet</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: or just .page-content li{text-indent: -1em;}

Answer (score 0):

Add simply `margin-left: -20px;` to `.page-content li:before`,
and optionally `margin-left: 20px;` to `.page-content ul`.

**Padding #1**: https://jsfiddle.net/swrufhzc/2/
**Padding #2**: https://jsfiddle.net/swrufhzc/3/